# HTML Input Type="url" for <a href =""> Effects

Tags: javascript, html

I need the following format 
`"<div><input type='url' id='link1' data-rowid='1' class='Link' value='here ...'/</div>"` 
for Jquery process.

But I want to achieve the appearance of "`<a href =''>here ...</a>`".

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: `ìnput` elements are replaced elements. So you may not be able to style them fully like other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try styling the input via CSS in a way that mimics a regular `<a>` tag:

```
#link1{
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    // etc, etc...
}
```

That will retain the functionality of the original `<input>` tag, but with the appearance of a link.

Comment: Thanks @Marco Del Valle, That is exactly what I want.  It works after used your codes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax to do that, for example

```
<div id="link" contenteditable="true"><a href="$link"><?php echo $link; ?></a></div>
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var message_status = $("#status");
    $("div[contenteditable=true]").blur(function () {
        var projectid = $(this).attr("id");
        var text = $(this).text();
        $.post('update.php', linkid + "=" + text, function (data) {
            if (data != '') {
                message_status.fadeIn();
                message_status.text(data);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    message_status.fadeOut()
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```